# Manipulating hexadecimal values in java

Tags: java, random, hex

I'm tying to make a Linear Congruential random number generator, and I want to select, say the first 16 bits of a 64-bit length hexadecimal value. How Can I do this in java? I've already created a (very) basic generated number based on the time of day.

My formula:

seed = 0x5D588B656C078965L * cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + 0x0000000000269EC3;

I just want to select the first 16 bits of this, I tried to think of how I would do this with an integer but the I don't think i can apply the same concepts here. Thanks!

Comment: `new Random().next(16);` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#next-int-

Comment: `int sixteenLeastSignificantBits = ((int) longValue) & 0xFFFF;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a long that has the first 16 bits and zeroes in the other positions, you can either use a bit mask or shifting.

Assuming by "first 16 bits" you mean the highest-order bits, then the mask looks like this:

```
long mask = 0xffff000000000000;
```

so that a '1' is in each bit position you want to retain, and a 0 elsewhere. Then do a logical 'and' of this with your original integer:

```
long result = seed & mask;
```

The other way is to shift your original to the right 48 bits, then left again 48 bits.

Comment: That's really cool! thank you, I've heard of bit masking before but I'm only in my first year of university so I don't have much experience

Comment: I think it instructive to work out what happens on a bit level -- for each '1' in the mask, a '1' or '0' will come through from the original unchanged; for each '0' in the mask, you will always get a 0 result from an 'and' operation. You can use a similar logic for *setting* values, using an 'or' operation, with '1' in places where you want to set the bit.

Comment: Remember that, on StackOverflow, if your question gets answered, mark it as the answer; if any answer helps you, upvote it. That's how reputations here are maintained.

Comment: Do you think that I would have any kind of data loss from this statement?                                                     seed = (int)0x5D588B656C078965L * cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + 0x0000000000269EC3;

Comment: The result will be missing all the bits you masked "out"; if you don't discard your original, you will still have them. But there is no way to mask out bits and NOT lose data.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have enough reputation to upvote

Comment: Oh I mean in casting as an int, because this hex number seems fairly large, I am aware of the size of an int though.

Comment: I've created a room named "chat with Howard P" - if you can join it we can discuss there...  EDIT oh, sorry, have to have 20 rep to talk in a chat room. Oh, well. Yes, if you cast from long to int, it is going to throw away half your bits.

Comment: It's a little off the purpose to declare a literal as `long` and cast it to `int`. If you need an `int`, just use an `int` literal.

Answer (score 0):

Bit shift:

```
long value = seed >>> 48;
```

or you can save it in an `int`:

```
int value = (int)(seed >> 48);
```

Usually, you would use the *last* bits of the seed to produce the random number, which makes for a one-way `mod` operation (ie "more random"), so:

```
seed & 0xFFFF
```

Comment: Thank you! I'd upvote but i dont have enough reputation yet

Comment: Actually, you don't even need a variable, you can just us `seed >>> 48` directly